# Can Mozilla Thunderbird show sent replies in threaded view?

Tags: email, thunderbird, threading

I would like for Thunderbird to show replies to threaded messages in with the received messages. Is this possible, even with an extension?

The desired behavior would be something like how Zimbra's threaded email view works.

Comment: Any updates on this issue in 2022??

Comment: It is coming it seems TB 114 development roadmap https://developer.thunderbird.net/planning/roadmap#conversational-view

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[GMail Conversation View](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/54035) does what you want without having to copy replies into your folders. Sometimes it doesn't properly pull in your replies, and it doesn't start conversations if you initiated them, but it is the most similar to gmail I have found.

Comment: Combine this and gatorbrit's answer and I've basically got what I want. Thanks guys!

Comment: 2-year update: Switched to Postbox, has excellent conversation view. TB is still lacking in this (and most) respects.

Comment: This plugin unfortunately makes significant changes to the Thunderbird UI going far beyond just showing replies in the same folder.

Comment: I don't know if it's improved but I was using GMail Conversation View a few years ago and it made Thunderbird a bit unstable.

Comment: The problem with this is when the thread is long , say more than 30 entries, it becomes too slow to be useful.

Comment: ThreadVis extension for Thunderbird

Comment: @huggie TreadVis sounds interesting but on clicking on the timeline items it jumps only to received emails; if my sent text is not on the body of the received, I get lost; do you believe there is some way it could jump to sent emails? or there could have a unique folder with them all so it could work that way? thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower Yes, it does jump between any folder. All mails, received or sent, are on the timeline.

Comment: Now if we could just [prevent the automatic expansion of a thread upon the open of a folder](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1214534).

Comment: Anyone just wanting to read mail threads on linux and not worry about anything else, you could try using the `geary` mail client

Answer (score 48):

You need to go to the account settings for the account and select Copies & Folders, then check the box "Place replies in the folder of the message being replied to"

Also enable sorting by thread.

THis will replicate the gmail effect I think.

Comment: Combine this and user30075's answer and I've basically got what I want. Thanks guys!

Comment: This works but it goes against Google’s recommendations for IMAP clients (to not make copies of sent messages, sent GMail already does that anyway), and slows down mail delivery by a factor of two as the message is not just sent but also copied into your folder (including big attachments). What is needed is to just *see* the sent message in the folder, not to really copy it there.

Comment: Obviously for POP and SMTP as opposed to IMAP setups this works a treat and doesn't duplicate messages.  The sent replies only appear in your inbox, not in your sent mail folder, which actually works really well in practice.

Answer (score 33):

It "is" built-in on thunderbird now, if you do the right steps:

There is the [Global Inbox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Global_Inbox) (if there isn't one, you have to activate it at `View >> Folders >> Unified` from [this tip](https://askubuntu.com/a/132858/46437))

Go on its properties at **"Select the folders to search:"**
and click on **"Choose..."**, you will see that your top inbox is checked;
just check the **"sent"** one, click **"ok"**, and **"Update"**.

Now, go to your top "inbox" that is the global one, activate the threaded column and you have a three with all incoming and outgoing messages!

Obs.: thunderbird version 31.4.0 here.

PS.: follow @hvd comment below to restrict the messages shown to a single account (in case of multiple email accounts)!

Comment: Or, if you prefer not to use the Global Inbox, create a custom search folder: right-click the account, choose "Search Messages", then "Save as Search Folder", and customise it exactly as you did. It's the same thing under the hood, but for me (with multiple mail accounts, that I do want to keep separate), looks closer to how I like my mail.

Comment: @hvd, worked great! I had to select "match all messages" option and it worked, thx!

Comment: Where exactly can I set the "Select the folders to search"? I enabled the unified folders but I can't find the further places.

Comment: @marmistrz right click and select properties, btw, my thunderbird is v.31.4.0

Comment: I went into the properties but I can't find the "Select the folders to choose" field/button/whatever

Comment: @marmistrz check the version of your thunderbird

Comment: 1:31.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: @marmistrz I just saw that the global inbox (named simply "inbox") is also a saved search, most probably there is some problem with your installation. [Here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-saved-searches#w_how-to-create-a-saved-search-folder) I found some other info, not sure if will help you.

Comment: I just installed thunderbird on my Mac yesterday, newest version of course. the unified inbox is not a saved search, there's no "select folders to search" on the properties pane, I had to create my own saved search folder.

Comment: @DavidDai cool, my answer is probably deprecated then, version 31.4.0. Add yours :)

Comment: This answer thread does exactly what the OP asked for without requiring external add-ons

Comment: @AquariusPower Does not work for me, I can only see received messages but not my.

Comment: Where is this "select folders to search"

Comment: This still falls short of a (crucial) feature: hiding entire threads when every incoming message is archived, but showing the entire thread if any single e-mail is not archived. Basically, from a UX pov, the threads become the element to archive / unarchive, instead of individual messages. This makes a huge difference and is, imo, implied in the question.

Comment: As of Jan 2024, this continues to work perfectly and is necessary to include Sent messages in reply to a thread in the thread, without any add-ons. Right click Inbox, choose Properties, then add the Sent folder(s).

Answer (score 6):

If you use Gmail. Your thunderbird will sync the folder structure which includes an **"All Mail**". Use this folder instead of "Inbox" and use the threaded view will make the threads include sent replies.

I prefer this way to the plugin "Thunderird Conversations" because the plugin is very slow to load when the thread is very long. And sometimes the plugin doesn' t display attachments properly. And this way avoids the extra costs of the option "Place replies in the folder of the message being replied to" will incur.

For other mail users, adding a new virtual folder might also do, see: [Combine in- and outgoing mail in Thunderbird in one folder](https://superuser.com/questions/107590/combine-in-and-outgoing-mail-in-thunderbird-in-one-folder?lq=1)
 . This inspired me that Gmail includes such a folder already.

Answer (score 3):

If you set Thunderbird to place sent mails in the Inbox folder you can achieve it. This works great for me. I use my Inbox as 'ongoing issues'. So, placing the sent messages (that could be thought of a new issue or a reply to an ongoing issue) in inbox is ok.

Comment: how would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Thunderbird can show sent replies in a threaded view.

- Right click on any message in a thread.
- Select `Open Message in Conversation`.
- Alternatively press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>.

A new tab will open showing the messages in a thread pulled from both 'Inbox' and 'Sent Mail'.

I wish this was available directly in the Inbox but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Copy Sent to Current](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/copy-sent-to-current/) extension to do what it says.... that way I have my sent emails in the sent folder for archival purposes as well as in the folder I was in when I composed the email.  That combined with the threaded view gets me the perfect conversation.

Edit: the only problem is that when you search for a conversation, it displays the replies both from your inbox/archives folder AND the sent folder, so perhaps you don't want to use this.  But I thought I'd put the option out there.

Answer (score -2):

Click on the header of the left-most (usually) column give you the threaded view.

Comment: While this enables thread view using mail in the inbox, it unfortunately does not show thread replies from the Sent folder--this is the behavior which I desire.

Comment: Try ThreadVis addon for Thunderbird.