# Combine in- and outgoing mail in Thunderbird in one folder

Tags: thunderbird, threading

I have configured Thunderbird with IMAP to an Exchange server. I have an Inbox and a Sent items folder. I can turn on message threads in the views for these folder, but the threads will only show the received and the sent messages respectively.

Can I have a folder that combines sent and received messages that will display all messages in a single thread? Think conversation view in Gmail.

Comment: Just get the addon called Thunderbird Conversations

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Mozilla Thunderbird show sent replies in threaded view?](http://superuser.com/questions/67488/can-mozilla-thunderbird-show-sent-replies-in-threaded-view)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new virtual folder which contains both incoming and sent messages.

When you create it, just choose the inbox and the "sent" folder and say "no conditions" (or corresponding, I'm German).

Nevertheless, the conversation -- or tree -- view seems not to work perfectly here with my TB 3.0.1.

Comment: Yeah, using a search folder works and I consider it the best option, since it's a virtual folder and doesn't change the items actual location. But threaded view doesn't always work well, even when received and sent messages are in one place. It's definitely no Gmail conversation view.

Comment: A neat idea but does not work at all when you have messages in folders: the virtual folder will show *all* sent messages, not just those in reply to a thread in the current folder.

Comment: The point made by @JesseGlick is my gripe with this solution, too. I have loads of messages and conversations in many subfolders, and get a lot of email. Obviously combining all sent and inbox is not a viable solution in this use case, as I can not see the discussions in the subfolders I'd like and need them bot be.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I like to do this as well.
I just configured Thunderbird to put copies of sent mail into my inbox.

Menu entry "Edit / Account settings...", tab "Copies & Folder",  then "When sending messages, automatically...".
Choose "Place a copy in", "Other", then choose your inbox. Done.

As a bonus, you might want to check "Place replies in the folder of the message being replied to".

This is in TB 3.1, BTW. Don't know if TB 2 has it.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Thunderbird 3.0, and I prefer the search folder option that Martin suggested.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/67488/can-mozilla-thunderbird-show-sent-replies-in-threaded-view also suggests this though it makes performance worse.

Answer (score 3):

See http://wiki.github.com/protz/GMail-Conversation-View/displaying-your-own-messages-in-the-inbox (warning: requires Thunderbird 3.1).

You might want to install the companion extension called "Gmail Conversation View" (cannot post more than 1 hyperlink) (full disclosure: I'm the author).

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/67488/can-mozilla-thunderbird-show-sent-replies-in-threaded-view/795667#795667).

I already [answered it there](https://superuser.com/a/795667/157532).

So basically you can visualize the full thread (incoming/outgoing) by activating Global Inbox and adding the Sent folder to its search list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still using Thunderbird 2.0.0.23 and the "Copy Sent to Current" extension which gives you the option of choosing the folder sent items get saved to.

By default it selects the current folder, so if when sending or replying to e-mails from your inbox it will choose that folder.

I don't know whether it works with Thunderbird 3 or not - I haven't thought about upgrading yet (but as it's now at 3.0.1 I might).

Comment: I believe TB 3 has this built-in -- see my answer.